# Solve in positive integers $x^2+3y^2=z^2$ and $x^2+y^2=5z^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solve the following equations in postive integers:

1. $x^2+3y^2=z^2$
2. $x^2+y^2=5z^2$

I have solved them using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) as a reference, but I am interested in other solutions, more "elegant" ones.
The equations are to be solved separate!!!

Comment: I don't see how there can be any non-trivial solution. If you subtract the two equations, you get 2y^2 = -4z^2. There can be no solution without making y or z imaginary, so only x=y=z=0 remains.

Comment: @Aganju I expect that this is two separate questions bundled together, not a simultaneous system.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited it

Comment: The complete primitive solution to $x^2+dy^2= z^2$ is given by $(p^2-dq^2)^2+d(2pq)^2 =  (p^2+dq^2)^2$. However, the one for $x^2+y^2 = dz^2$ needs an initial solution.

Comment: @Tito Piezas III now that I take a better look at it, both of them remind me of Pells equation. I know, you have to have a 1 one the other side, but I think there is also a general formula for it.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII no. That may work in class number one. Compare $p^2 + 5 q^2 \neq 3,$ but $2^2 + 5 \cdot 1^2 = 3^2$

Comment: Also $1+3=4.....$

Comment: @WillJagy: Ah, I stand corrected. The complete _rational_ parameterization is $(p^2-dq^2)^2r^2+d(2pqr)^2=(p^2+dq^2)^2r^2$. I should not have dismissed the scaling factor $r$.

Comment: In General it is necessary to consider equations in the General case. For example.  $x^2+y^2=az^2$

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1051335

Answer (score 4):

People are not careful with these. With $x^2 + 3 y^2 = z^2;$ with odd $z,$ we indeed get
$$ (r^2 - 3 s^2)^2 + 3(2rs)^2 = (r^2 + 3 s^2)^2. $$ This does not give primitive solutions with even $z,$ which come from
$$ \left( \frac{r^2 - 3 s^2}{2} \right)^2 + 3 (rs)^2 = \left( \frac{r^2 + 3 s^2}{2} \right)^2  $$ with both $r,s$ odd

For $x^2 + y^2 = 5 z^2$ primitive means $z$ odd, we take $x$ to be the even one.
$$ (2u^2 - 2 u v - 2 v^2)^2 + (u^2 + 4 uv - v^2)^2 = 5 (u^2 + v^2)^2 $$

Answer (score 3):

In general, given one solution to,

$$a_1y_1^2+a_2y_2^2+\dots+ a_ny_n^2 = 0$$

then an infinite more can be found *without scaling*. For example,

> $n=3$

$$ax_1^2+bx_2^2+cx_3^2 = (ay_1^2+by_2^2+cy_3^2)(az_1^2+bz_2^2+cz_3^2)^2$$

where,

$$x_1, x_2, x_3 = uy_1-vz_1,\;  uy_2-vz_2,\;  uy_3-vz_3\\
\text{and}\\
u,v = az_1^2+bz_2^2+cz_3^2,\; 2(ay_1z_1+by_2z_2+cy_3z_3)$$

If you have an initial solution $ay_1^2+by_2^2+cy_3^2 = 0$, then the identity gives you an infinite more with *three* free variables $z_1, z_2, z_3$.

> $n=4$

$$ax_1^2+bx_2^2+cx_3^2+dx_4^2 = (ay_1^2+by_2^2+cy_3^2+dy_4^2)(az_1^2+bz_2^2+cz_3^2+dz_4^2)^2$$

where,

$$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 = uy_1-vz_1,\;  uy_2-vz_2,\;  uy_3-vz_3,\; uy_4-vz_4\\
\text{and}\\
u,v = az_1^2+bz_2^2+cz_3^2+dz_4^2,\; 2(ay_1z_1+by_2z_2+cy_3z_3+dy_4z_4)$$

Likewise, you now have *four* free variables $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$.

And so on for any $n$. I trust the pattern is easy to see?

> **Example:**

For $x^2+y^2 = 5z^2$, we have $a,b,c = 1,1,-5$, and initial solution $y_1, y_2, y_3 = 1,2,1$. Using the formula, we get,

$$x = z_1^2 + z_2^2 - 5 z_3^2 - 2 z_1 (z_1 + 2 z_2 - 5 z_3)\\
y = 2 ( z_1^2 + z_2^2 - 5 z_3^2) - 2 z_2(z_1 + 2 z_2 - 5 z_3)\\
z =  z_1^2 + z_2^2 - 5 z_3^2 - 2 z_3(z_1 + 2 z_2 - 5 z_3)$$

for three free variables $z_i$. Let, $z_2 = u + 2 v + 2 z_1,\; z_3 = v + z_1$, then $z_1$ cancels out and we recover W. Jagy's version in the other answer.

Comment: I like the solution of yours. It is indeed one way to generate solutions to the equation I gave, but I should also have a proof that those are maybe the only solutions to it, bcs I am interested in all solutions

Comment: @HeatTheIce: I'm not completely sure, but I assume the three degrees of freedom $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are enough to cover all solutions $x,y,z$ if one takes into account sign changes and the permutations $x,y$ and $y,x$. I edited to give an example.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be infinite solutions to these equations but only two patterns jump out for both of them.

$\text{For equation 1. }$ are $x=z, y=0$ because no integer $y$ yields $3y^2$ is a perfect square.
\begin{equation}
y=\sqrt{\frac{z^2-x^2}{3}}\quad \text{for}\quad x,z\in\mathbb{N}\land z\ge x
\end{equation}
some solutions are
$$(x,0,x)\qquad (x,x,2x)$$

other solutions do not show a simple pattern

\begin{equation}
(1,4,7)\quad
(1,15,26)\quad
(2,8,14)\quad
(2,30,52)\quad
(3,12,21)\quad
(4,16,28)\quad
(6,24,42)\quad
(7,28,49)\quad
(7,4,1)\quad
(8,32,56)\quad
(11,21,38)\quad
(11,24,43)\quad
(11,4,13)\quad
(11,5,14)\quad
(13,20,37)\quad
(13,3,14)\quad
(13,8,19)\quad
(22,10,28)\quad
(22,8,26)\quad
(23,12,31)\quad
(23,7,26)\quad
(26,16,38)\quad
(26,6,28)\quad
(33,12,39)\quad
(33,15,42)\quad
(37,5,38)\quad
(39,24,57)\quad
(39,9,42)\quad
(44,16,52)\quad
(44,20,56)\quad
(46,14,52)\quad
(52,12,56)\quad
\end{equation}

$\\ \text{For equation 2.}$
$$z = \sqrt{\frac{x^2 + y^2}{5}}\quad\text{for}\quad x\in\mathbb{N}$$
some solutions are
\begin{equation}
(x,2x,x)\qquad  
\bigg(x,\frac{11x}{2},\frac{5x}{2}\bigg)
\end{equation}

other solutions do not show a simple pattern
\begin{equation}
(1,38,17)\quad
(2,29,13)\quad
(2,76,34)\quad
(4,58,26)\quad
(6,87,39)\quad
(11,82,37)\quad
(19,62,29)\quad
(22,19,13)\quad
(22,31,17)\quad
(22,61,29)\quad
(22,89,41)\quad
(31,22,17)\quad
(38,41,25)\quad
(41,38,25)\quad
(44,38,26)\quad
(44,62,34)\quad
(55,10,25)\quad
(57,66,39)\quad
(58,4,26)\quad
(58,59,37)\quad
(58,71,41)\quad
\end{equation}